# Customize metric visualization in MLFlow UI when using mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()

Tags: tf.keras, mlflow

I'm trying to integrate MLFlow to my project. Because I'm using `tf.keras.fit_generator()` for my training so I take advantage of `mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()`([docs](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tensorflow.html#mlflow.tensorflow.autolog) here) to enable automatic logging of metrics and parameters:

```
    model = Unet()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(LEARNING_RATE)

    metrics = [IOUScore(threshold=0.5), FScore(threshold=0.5)]
    model.compile(optimizer, customized_loss, metrics)

    callbacks = [
        tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model.h5", save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, mode='min'),
        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', profile_batch=0, update_freq='batch'),
    ]


    train_dataset = Dataset(src_dir=SOURCE_DIR)

    train_data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

   
    with mlflow.start_run():
        mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()
        mlflow.log_param("batch_size", BATCH_SIZE)

        model.fit_generator(
            train_data_loader,
            steps_per_epoch=len(train_data_loader),
            epochs=EPOCHS,
            callbacks=callbacks   
            )
```

I expected something like this (just a demonstration taken from the [docs](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#visualizing-metrics)):

[image: Visualization on the docs]

However, after the training finished, this is what I got:

[image: f1_score visualization]

How can I configure so that the metric plot will update and display its value at each epoch instead of just showing the latest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around, I found [this issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2390) related to my problem above. Actually, all my metrics just logged once each training (instead of each epoch as my intuitive thought). The reason is I didn't specify the `every_n_iter` parameter in `mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()`, which indicates how many 'iterations' must pass before MLflow logs metric executed (see the [docs](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tensorflow.html#mlflow.tensorflow.autolog)). So, changing my code to:

`mlflow.tensorflow.autolog(every_n_iter=1)`

fixed the problem.

P/s: Remember that in TF 2.x, an 'iteration' is an epoch (in TF 1.x it's a batch).